# Why are my unit tests not run?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have made a function that counts the number of vowels (and it works, according to the print).

I am a bit new to unit tests, and currently when I run the script, it is not saying 0 tests are ran.

What am I doing incorrect here?

```
import unittest

# data = raw_input("Please type a sentence: ")

def countVowels(string):
    count = 0
    for char in string:
      if char in 'AEIOUaeiou':
        count += 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        return 'even'
    else:
        return 'odd'

class VowelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def even(self):
        self.assertEqual(countVowels('Hello'), 'even')
    def odd(self):
        self.assertEqual(countVowels('Hi'), 'odd')


print countVowels("Hello")
print countVowels('hi')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html): "The [...] tests are defined with methods **whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the name of your tests, show begin with the word `test`. For example:

```
def testAdding():
    pass

def testSubtracting():
    pass
```

Comment: Derp. Yup. Exactly it. Yay syntax!